# How do I refer a value of an object as a generic in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a signature for this function:

```
export function objToArray(obj){
    let ret = [];
    for(const key of Object.keys(obj)){
        ret.push(Object.assign({objKey: key.toString()}, obj[key]));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

So for an object of type T that contains values of type U I want to return `Array<U & {objKey: string}>`. I can't figure out how to do this with typescript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  A type `T` has keys of type `keyof T` and values of type `T[keyof T]`.  Your function would therefore be typed like this:

```
export function objToArray<T extends object>(
 obj: T): Array<T[keyof T] & { objKey: string }>{
    let ret = [];
    // Object.keys() returns `string[]` but we will assert as `Array<keyof T>`
    for(const key of Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>){
        ret.push(Object.assign({objKey: key.toString()}, obj[key]));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. From the docs on generics I saw keyof but didn't see any example dealing with values like T[keyof T].

Comment: Thank you @jcalz I have been trying to do exactly this. However, it seems to complain at `Ojbect.keys(obj)` see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwgIwCsAVCAQSigEMBPAHmID4AKAwgLjmIEpOLr6xANoBrYDQgIuAXTgAyOAG88RANLjOAZxhRMKAOZwAvo0UBYAFBxrcADbB4UB3AC8cIdIDclm3AD0fnAA8kTAGAB0YjSazNxwTjBIUCiacAAG2roGHmlw+EjwAO7AcIWYtrZwVJqawLBVqWn8tHRRklyMaT42CNDMaDjacFF4UiGEYTCR4jFscdVwzfRtUkzc5la+NgnhYEiaABbM45Ph1ZqY+ijMimzqNJxR4TAQAMo6evqxRgA0KoSicTSbjcbybaxGbrWBJJXAJMFGIA). I changed it to `objToArray<T extends Object>` is that right

Comment: Also is there a way to inherit optional values ,without explicitly passing a type. I.e. in this [playground](https://tsplay.dev/ND8k8N) it says that greeting does not exist on the type? Much gratitude for your guidance.

Comment: In the five years since this answer was posted, `Object.keys()` was modified to only accept objects; `T extends object` (lowercase, not `Object`) is the required fix.

Comment: As for your followup question this comment section isn't a great place to deal with it.  I might look at it sometime but I can't commit to that; your best bet is to post a new question or find an existing question about that.

Comment: ‍♂️ doh I meant lowercase object. Thank you. And will keep searching or post another question about it inheriting optional values.